# How to make a table from JSON? ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am really a beginner with python, but I am trying to use IBM's sentiment analyzer to make a dataset.  I get a JSON response which I want to put into a table.  So far what I have is:

```
response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
    text = df_text,
    features=Features(sentiment=SentimentOptions(targets=['Pericles']))).get_result()
print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))

respj = json.dumps(response['sentiment'])
respj
```

which prints

```
'{"targets": [{"text": "Pericles", "score": -0.939436, "label": "negative"}], "document": {"score": -0.903556, "label": "negative"}}'
```

Now it is at this point that I would really like to make a pandas table with this data.  Ideally, I would like all the above information formated like -> Text | text score | Document score

I don't really need the label positive or negative but it doesn't hurt to have it.  How would I accomplish this? Right now when I try

```
json_df = pd.read_json(respj)
json_df.head()
```

I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-b06d8a1caf3f> in <module>
----> 1 json_df = pd.read_json(respj)
      2 json_df.head()

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    212                 else:
    213                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 214             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    215 
    216         return cast(F, wrapper)

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression)
    606         return json_reader
    607 
--> 608     result = json_reader.read()
    609     if should_close:
    610         filepath_or_buffer.close()

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in read(self)
    729             obj = self._get_object_parser(self._combine_lines(data.split("\n")))
    730         else:
--> 731             obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)
    732         self.close()
    733         return obj

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _get_object_parser(self, json)
    751         obj = None
    752         if typ == "frame":
--> 753             obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
    754 
    755         if typ == "series" or obj is None:

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in parse(self)
    855 
    856         else:
--> 857             self._parse_no_numpy()
    858 
    859         if self.obj is None:

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1086 
   1087         if orient == "columns":
-> 1088             self.obj = DataFrame(
   1089                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1090             )

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    433             )
    434         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 435             mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    436         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    437             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
    252             arr if not is_datetime64tz_dtype(arr) else arr.copy() for arr in arrays
    253         ]
--> 254     return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    255 
    256 

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
     62     # figure out the index, if necessary
     63     if index is None:
---> 64         index = extract_index(arrays)
     65     else:
     66         index = ensure_index(index)

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in extract_index(data)
    366 
    367             if have_dicts:
--> 368                 raise ValueError(
    369                     "Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering."
    370                 )

ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering
```

If anyone can give me some tips as to how to make the table I am trying to make I would really appreciate it.  Also if anyone can explain the error I have right now that would be really great too.  I think I get the basic premise that it's because the JSON has two incompatible "tables" in it already.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to dump the `response['sentiment']` as a JSON string if you just want to turn it into a DataFrame. Use [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) instead.

It seems that `response['sentiment']` looks something like

```
>>> response['sentiment']

{
    "targets": [{"text": "Pericles", 
                 "score": -0.939436, 
                 "label": "negative"}], 
    "document": {"score": -0.903556, 
                 "label": "negative"}
}
```

Then, you just need

```
df = pd.json_normalize(response['sentiment'], 
                       record_path='targets',
                       meta=[['document','score'], ['document','label']])
```

**Output**

```
>>> df

       text     score     label document.score document.label
0  Pericles -0.939436  negative      -0.903556       negative
```

---

Optionally, you can rename the columns afterwards as you wish using [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html?highlight=rename#pandas.DataFrame.rename):

```
cols_mapping = {
    'text': 'Text', 
    'score': 'Text Score', 
    'label': 'Text Label', 
    'document.score': 'Document Score', 
    'document.label': 'Document Label'
}

df = df.rename(columns=cols_mapping)

>>> df 

       Text  Text Score Text Label Document Score Document Label
0  Pericles   -0.939436   negative      -0.903556       negative
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work for you:

```py
targets = {k: [t[k] for t in j['targets']] for k in j['targets'][0].keys()}
doc_scores = [j['document']['score']] * len(j['targets'])
pd.DataFrame({'document_score': doc_scores, **targets})
```